# Prove $S^c$ is not closed under addition using addition and the additive identity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Can anybody help me with this? The question is:

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $S \not = \emptyset$ and $S \not = \mathbb{R}$. Define $S^c =\{x\in \mathbb{R}:x \not \in S\}$. Suppose that $S$ is closed under addition AND closed under the additive inverse. Prove $S^c$ is not closed under addition. There is an example where $S$ and $S^c$ are both closed under multiplication.

My attempt at the proof is:

I will prove this directly. That is, I will assume choose two elements $x,y \in S^c$ and show that $x+y \not \in S^c$. This means, I will have to show $x+y \in S$. We know $S$ is a subset of the real numbers that is not the empty set nor the set of real numbers. I will choose elements $x$ and $y$ in $S^c$ and add them to each other to get $x+y$. We will let $y$ be $-x$ so we get $x+(-x)$ which we know is 0 by the definition of additive identity. Since 0 is not in the empty set and it is in a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, we know 0 is in $S$ therefore proving $S^c$ is not closed under addition.

We will now provide an example where $S$ and $S^c$ are both closed under multiplication. $S$ and $S^c$ are both closed under multiplication when there is an element $y \in S$ such that $y=0$ and there is an element $x \in S^c$ such that $x=0$. This is because anything multiplied by zero is zero by a proof proven previously in class. Thus we know $S$ and $S^c$ are both closed under multiplication in this case which concludes the proof.

I am pretty sure this is incorrect in many ways, so I was wondering if anyone can help me?

Comment: your additive case proof looks okay, but for the multiplication case you can't have $0\in S$ and $0\in S^c$

Comment: "Since $0$ is not in the empty set and it is in a subset of $\Bbb R$" is not an argument. Also, while I'll grant you that you can pick $x\in S^\complement$ because $S^\complement$ is not empty, you have to make an argument why you can pick $y=-x$, i.e., why it must be that $-x\in S^\complement$.

Comment: "when there is an element $y∈S$ such that $y=0$ and there is an element $x∈S^\complement$ such that $x=0$" we can neither conclude that $S$ and $S^\complement$ are closed under multiplication, nor is it even possible as $S\cap S^\complement=\emptyset$

Comment: Take $a\in S$ and $b\in S^{c}$. These exist because both sets are non-empty. Then $a+b$ belongs to wither $S$ or $S^{c}$. Assume that $a+b\in S$. Then $(a+b)+(-a)=b\notin S$, which contradicts that $S$ is closed by additive inverses and addition. Therefore, $a+b\in S^{c}$. Observe that $-b\notin S$, otherwise $b\in S$. Since $(a+b)+(-b)=a\notin S^{c}$, this shows that $S^{c}$ isn't closed by addition.

Comment: For the example about multiplication you can take $S=\{0\}$ and $S^{c}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\ x\neq0\}$.